# How to make a CSS accordion auto close open content when going from section to section

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a css accordion that i need to auto close when each title is clicked.  This way only one section will be open at a time. Right now they all stay open.

HTML

```
<section class="ac-container">

  <div>
    <input id="ac-1" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="ac-1"> title 1</label>
    <article class="ac-small">
      <p>some content</p>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="ac-2" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="ac-2">title 2</label>
    <article class="ac-small">
      <p>some content </p>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="ac-3" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox" />
    <label for="ac-3">title 3</label>
    <article class="ac-small">
      <p>some content</p>
    </article>
  </div>

</section>
```

CSS

```
.ac-container {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.ac-container h3 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: -70px;
    width: 500px
}

.ac-container h1 {
    font-size: 3.2em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 370px;
    color: #eb519c; 
}

.ac-container p {
    margin-left: 40px
}

.ac-container{
    width: 450px;
    margin: 10px auto 30px auto;
    text-align: left;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
}
.ac-container label{
    font-family: 'forced_squaremedium', helvetica     , sans-serif;
    padding: 5px 60px; 
    position: relative;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    z-index: 20;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 33px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    background: #ffffff;
}
.ac-container label:hover{
    background: #2d2d2d;
}
.ac-container input:checked + label,
.ac-container input:checked + label:hover{
    background: #2d2d2d;
    color: #5dc8d6;
    background-image: url(../img/pinkBulletTurn.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 3.1% -.1%;
}

.ac-container label:hover:after,
.ac-container input:checked + label:hover:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    right: 413px;
    top: 7px;
    background: transparent url(../img/whiteBullet.png) no-repeat center center;    
}
.ac-container input:checked + label:hover:after{
    background-image: url(../img/blueBullet.png);
    background-position:center bottom;
}
.ac-container input{
    display: none;
    background-image: url(../img/whiteBullet.png);
}
.ac-container article{
    background: #43535b;
    margin-top: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
    -moz-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
    -o-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
    -ms-transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
    transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.6s linear;
}
.ac-container article p{
    font-style: italic;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 23px;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 20px;
}
.ac-container input:checked ~ article{
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.1s linear;
    -moz-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.1s linear;
    -o-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.1s linear;
    -ms-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.1s linear;
    transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.1s linear;
}
.ac-container input:checked ~ article.ac-small{
    height: auto;
}
.ac-container input:checked ~ article.ac-medium{
    height: 180px;
}
.ac-container input:checked ~ article.ac-large{
    height: 230px;
}

.ac-container label {
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
    background-image: url(../img/pinkBullet.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 2.5%
}
```

I made code pen of it: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvBKby

Thanks!

Comment: it is helpful, but I didn't want to leave one box open... I was kind of hoping someone might offer another solution.

Answer (score 3):

You only need to change, in your `input` elements:

```
type="checkbox"
```

To:

```
type="radio"
```

But you should note that with this, always a tab will be open.

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjbEmL)